# Receiving "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" while connecting to "https:" site

Tags: ssl, java-7, indexoutofboundsexception, bouncycastle, sslexception

I am trying to connect to a "https://" site which supports "TLSv1" protocol and the following cipher suites,

TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 4096 bits
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 4096 bits

using Apache's httpclient (Java platform - JDK 1.7)

Its working fine in JDK1.8 (which has support for Cipher suites with DH parameters > 1024 bits)

But its failing in JDK 1.7 with the following exception,

```
main, handling exception: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 50                               ......P
main, called closeSocket()
main, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 64
```

As suggested in the workaround here,

http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6521495,
I used tried using Bouncy Castle Provider but still getting the same exception.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is, you are using 2048 DH key with TLS v1 while its compatible with TLS v1.2, So you can resolve it by three ways:

1) Upgrade your JDK version to 1.8

2) Disable all DHE ciphers from server

3) Use 1048 DH key on server

for more details, see [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/209245/ssl-exception-error-in-wesphere-application-server.html)